# Continuous differentiability of transition maps in the definition of a differentiable manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I don't understand a requirement of the definition of a differentiable manifold. For an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ we begin with charts $\varphi:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$, which are homeomorphisms, and require that in an atlas, for any two charts $\varphi$ and $\phi$ that, $\varphi\circ\phi^{-1}$ be continuously differentiable. Why continuously? I get that imposing that condition is the only way to talk about a continuously differentiable map between manifolds, since there needs to be a consistent local notion of continuity of the derivative. However, is there no value to studying manifolds where this desideratum isn't met? Are there things that can be gained from dropping this requirement, for example, some topological manifolds can't be given differential structures, could they be given differential structures without continuously differentiable transition maps?

Comment: The implicit function theorem only holds for continuously differentiable functions, and this theorem is the basis for the preimage/submersion theorem, which is one of the cornerstones of the theory of differentiable manifolds. We would lose this very important theorem if we didn't impose continuous differentiability.

Comment: In fact, it is frequently assumed that transition maps are infinitely differentiable. This helps in order to get a clean abstract definition of tangent vectors, etc.

Comment: What is there to be gained by allowing charts with discontinuously differentiable transition maps? Personally, I cannot think of an example right now where that would allow some different topologies. Generally when two such maps exist, there exist other maps covering the same regions with continuously differentiable transitions. In which case all that allowing the discontinuous versions does is make theorems impossible to prove without giving you anything new in their place. My imagination is not a viable limit on math, but can you give one example where it would be useful?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, if one further weakened the condition to Lipschitz. This allowed for analysis on topological manifolds.

Comment: @PS I don't know if it would be useful, that's why I asked the question. However, I don't find the answer "there's less structure so you can't prove as many theorems" satisfying. Firstly, generality is nice, and some theorems go from obvious to deep. Secondly, it's not necessarily true. If the objects of a category have less structure than those of another, that doesn't mean that the category is globally simpler. It could, e.g., have different limits or co-limits or interesting functors. Group theory is worth studying even if its objects have less structure than those of ring theory.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - How so? It seems to be to be just the opposite. We are not talking about the definitions of maps on the manifold. What we are talking about here is the definition of the manifold itself - how well the coordinate patches fit together. Weakining that *might* allow a broader class of manifolds (which is what I don't see an example of), but it also weakens what you can actually prove *on* those manifolds. You can only define regularity of maps on the manifolds up to the regularity of those charts. No higher.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is a highly nontrivial theorem of Sullivan that every topological manifold of dimension $\ne 4$ admits a Lipschitz atlas and that any two such structures are isomorphic. This allows one to do analysis on topological manifolds which otherwise requires smoothness.